# Javascript, Jquery - Google TTS works on local machine but not on server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a prototype for a text-to-speech chat system and come across a problem with my code. On my local machine (running on c:/) the user enters a text and converts it to speech and it works great. But when i put the website on my server the function will not work at all. Any idea what i can do to make it work ?

Relevant code :

```
<input type="text" name="text" id="text">
<a href="#" class="say" > Send</a>
<audio src="" class= "speech" hidden></audio>

$(function() {

    // Text to speech
    $('a.say').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($('#text').val() == '' ) { //Validering av tekstfelt
    alert('Vennligst skriv noe i tekstboksen.');
    }
    else {

    var text = $('input[name ="text"]').val();
    text = encodeURIComponent(text);
    console.log(text);
    var url = "https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=" + text + "&tl=no";
    $('audio').attr('src', url).get(0).play();
     });
    });
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=whats%20up&tl=no

Comment: After searching around for a solution i at least found the problem. It seems google translate have a block installed so to prevent people to use the server. Anyone know a way around  this ?